# WPF columns not spanning correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a group box containing some bound data:

```
  <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="#eeeeee" Margin="10,0,0,0" width="250">
        <GroupBox Padding="5" Header="Lists">                            
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox" BorderBrush="#FFECECEC" ItemsSource="{Binding Lists}" SelectionChanged="Panel_SelectionChanged" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource Pan}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource Del}" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <Image Source="../Resources/Delete2.png" Width="32" />
                    </Button>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
```

The issue is that the two columns containing the text box and delete button arn't spanning correctly. Check out the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property to your ListBox

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```